# spring-cloud-consul is not compatible with spring-boot-2.0.0.M1

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-consul

It seems that current release of **spring-cloud-consul**(which is **1.2.2-snapshot** at this moment) is not compatible with **spring-boot-2.0.0.M1**.

As a new comer of microservice, i'm trying to integrate consul into my project to support service registry, but the project failed to start after I insert the consul starter into the pom.xml.

All right, here comes the sample code:

```
//DemoApplication.java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}

//pom.xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>  <!-- evertything works fine -->
    <!--<version>2.0.0.M1</version>--> <!-- project fail to start -->
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-all</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

....some other irrelevant configs

//application.properties
spring.cloud.consul.port = 8500
spring.cloud.consul.host = localhost
```

As above code shows, everything works fine if using **spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE**, while it failed to start project when using **spring-boot-2.0.0.M1**, with complain of following:

```
13:52:15.444 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>([Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:157)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:98)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:64)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:72)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:328)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1278)
    at com.cmcc.syw.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:11)
```

Any suggestions about the reason?

Comment: AFAIK, spring cloud doesn't support spring-boot 2.0 yet.